# Cannot download Gdata

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, gdata-api

So I'm trying to use Google's gdata in my app, but in order to get the files, it says online I have to use svn.  I've heard of svn before, but im not entirely sure what it is or how to use it.  ive been googling and looking online for the past two days and i cant seem to figure out how to get the files into my project.  ive tried using the svn thing build into xcode, but i get an error.  see the pics below.  Thanks in advance

Also, I know how to use gdata once i get it added to my project, i just need to get that far.
[image: this is what i see on the side of the repository organizer]

[image: this is what i see when i look at the svn in xcode]

[image: this is the error i get everytime]